# Mobile number tracking

Tags: web-application, public-key-infrastructure, mobile, user-tracking, simcard

Is there any way we can track our mobile when it is lost?

I have done a google search on the same and found that we have websites which give us the details of where the SIM was purchased & Operator but not exactly where it is now. One example of such website is http://bmobile.in/.

I have heard that we can track with the IMEI number, but it does not help. It gives information about "Thief Tracker" software application which could be installed on mobile.

I would like to know a similar or better app which can be installed on a desktop or laptop which helps us to track our mobile numbers with or without IMEI number.

Comment: The phone service provider may be able to track it

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer - No.

You need to install tracking software **before** the phone was stolen. It's similar to a tracker for a car. Once you install the tracker you get location information. Without it, you don't.

Comment: Can you share the links of the best tracking softwares?

Comment: No. This is not a recommendation site. We do have a software recommendation stack exchange though...